# assistance with debugging object expected in ie7

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I work on [this site](http://www.biome.sk). In IE7 I get this error:

```
object expected line 475 code 0
```

Can anybody advise me how can I debug this?

Comment: Load the un-minified JQuery file and see if you still get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as you are using IE7 download the Developer Toolbar

- http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18359

In newer versions of IE8 this is already built in and you can access it by pressing F12.